# Translating "Through Intellect, Strength" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, meaning

> *Per Intellectum, Vis*

What would you fix? Trying to come up with a theme / catchphrase for a family event. I want to signify respect for education, the scientific method and observation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Intellectus* means "understanding." I think it's a fine enough phrase, but personally I'd go with something a bit more idiomatic. You could do:

- *Vis per mentem*, "strength through the mind"

*Mens* is often used as metonymy for the "intellect." Cf. Juvenal's *mens sana in corpore sano*.

You could also do something like *in scientia* or *in eruditione*, though they don't sound as snappy.

More problematic is *vis*, which is most often physical strength or even violence. For a more general strength, you could do something like:

- *fortior per mentem*

Here *fortior* means "stronger", and the phrase would correlate the use of *mens* with becoming *fortis*, "strong."

Finally, if you're thinking about political strength (which, I suspect, you're not, since it's for a family event), you could substitute *potestas* for *vis*.

Ultimately, though, I'd rest with:

> *Fortior per mentem*

Even then context matters, as it could, literally, mean "stronger throughout the mind," though I myself kind of like the double meaning there.

Comment: +1. One thing to note though is that *fortior* is masculine singular, and if the phrase isn't referring to a single male person it may not be suitable. ("substitute vis for potestas" --> "substitute potestas for vis"?) Btw I think the "physical strength" sense of *vis* is mainly in the plural -- the singular for more abstract "force" seems fine to me.

Comment: @TKR *Fortior* is both masculine and feminine.

Comment: Oops, you're right of course. But still referring to a single person, or at least a single entity -- if the referent is a family, I would think *fortiores* is better.

Comment: @TKR True, *fortiores* would be good if there is an implied *nos*, i.e. if the family is working together, though there could also be an implied "each," which would also work for multiple people and keep the singular. I'd chalk it up to style. Interestingly, the Romans often used a collective singular where we would often use a plural. And then there is the poetic plural, where we would use a singular!